# Почему preg_match_all возвращает пустой массив?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В функции "getStartPositionInclude" регулярное выражение возвращает пустой массив, если параметр $str является многобайтовой строкой (содержит символы Кириллицы), флаг /u в регулярке присутствует, а если параметр $str содержит только символы английского алфавита, то работает корректно, т.е в переменную-массив $words записываются слова из $str. Почему это происходит и как можно исправить это?

```
function getStartPositionInclude( $str ){
    $words = [];
    preg_match_all( "/[^\W\d][\w]*/u", $str, $words );
    $words = $words[0];

    $lastWordindex = count($words) - 1;
    $positionSymbol = mb_strripos($str, $words[$lastWordindex - 1]);

    return $positionSymbol ;
}
```

Comment: Дайте конкретный кейс, напр. на [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) ибо всё работает как с кирилицей, так и без

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Токены `\w` и `\W` матчат только латинские буквы `[a-zA-Z]` - буквенные диапазоны других локалей, в эти токены могут быть **не** включены (зависит от реализации).

Собственно, `\w` == `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` и `\W` == `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

> \w stands for “word character”. **It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_].** Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits. In most flavors that support Unicode, \w includes many characters from other scripts. **There is a lot of inconsistency about which characters are actually included.**
> ([источник](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html))

> Another **special** sequence that may appear at the start of a pattern is (*UCP). This has the same effect as setting the PCRE2_UCP option: it causes sequences such as \d and \w to use Unicode properties to determine character types, instead of recognizing only characters with codes less than 256 via a lookup table. (...)
> **Some applications that allow their users to supply patterns may wish to restrict them for security reasons.** If the PCRE2_NEVER_UCP option is passed to pcre2_compile(), (*UCP) is not allowed, and its appearance in a pattern causes an error.
> ([источник](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html))

---

- Либо напиши в выражении что-то типа `[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9_]`
  <sub>(или `[a-zа-яё0-9_]` с флагом `i`)</sub>
- Либо используй [юникодовские классы (категории)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) расширенного PCRE типа `\p{L}`
  <sub>(предварительно уточнив, есть ли их поддержка в используемой тобой версии PHP, а то мало ли...)</sub>

---

**p.s.:** `[\w]*` в конце регулярки из вопроса - это абсолютно то же самое что `\w*` (можно смело убрать `[` `]`).

Comment: [Как так-то?](https://regex101.com/r/fzeYWo/1)

Comment: @InDevX, RTFM... специально для умов ограниченных частными случаями, в ответ добавлены цитаты со ссылками.

Comment: Ну, что тут сказать.. Это был "намёк" на то что надо разъяснить данный момент, но раз скатываемся в оскорбления то пускай минус и дальше висит

Comment: @InDevX, даже не собирался оспаривать... признаю как чужое право считать констатацию оскорблением, так и минус к ответу. Если же к ответу есть еще и ***конструктивные*** вопросы/уточнения/правки - буду столь же рад их увидеть, как и сообщество.

Comment: Выдавать своё мнение за констатацию это да, конструктивно.

Comment: @InDevX, понятно что примириться с наличием мнений у посторонних может быть тяжело, но вынужден напомнить, что комменты здесь предназначены вовсе не для перфомансов а-ля _"так пускай же мой минус висит"_ / _"сам такой!"_, и повторно прошу конкретизировать претензии именно к ответу. А если таковые отсутствуют - то предлагаю прекратить драматизмъ, во избежание расширения полученных психоэмоциональных ран.

Comment: Обиделись, что ли? Или к чему эти язвительные комментарии? Сами же провоцируете на эту демагогию.. Можете модератора "позвать", если считаете комментарии неуместными. Пожалуй, больше отвечать не буду.

Comment: @InDevX, хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Благодарю! Замена регулярного выражения решила проблему! preg_match_all( "/\p{L}/", $str, $words );

Comment: @Юрий, я мало пишу на PHP и сейчас могу ошибиться, но по-моему, с таким выражением в `$words` окажется массив строк из одной буквы (т.к. после токена `\p{L}` отсутствует квантификатор, например `+`)... такой результат - это действительно то что требуется?